# Unknown Code Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I've been trying my hardest to understand the lessons in W3Schools but it is not working somehow!

I've edited it so that you guys would get it much better.

This is the index.html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Get data as JSON from a PHP file on the server.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj, i, x, j = "";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myObj = JSON.stringify(this.response);
        myObj1 = JSON.parse(myObj);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj1.stuid;
  alert(myObj1);
  
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "sing.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the sing.php

```html
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sacapp";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 
$result = $conn->query("SELECT stuid, stuname, stucourse, stustat, stulyear, stulog FROM stuinfo");
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

and here is the result of `myObj1` `[{"stuid":"10-00002","stuname":"Meratis, Velino","stucourse":"InfoTech","stustat":"0","stulyear":"4","stulog":"feb 16 2017"},{"stuid":"10-00003","stuname":"Melker, Alana","stucourse":"CivilEngi","stustat":"1","stulyear":"5","stulog":"feb 16 2017"}]`

but the `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj1.stuid;` only returns an `Undefined` answer... what went wrong here?

I don't know what the hell is wrong with it. Can someone please point out any mistakes?

Comment: Remove the markup from `sing.php`

Comment: I'm not a fan of [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) myself

Comment: oh forgot about that but then it just says undefined

Comment: @Arkonsol where/what says undefined excatly.

Comment: just edited it. still the same. it's either undefined or has that error :/

Comment: and those [] that encases the {} maybe the reason why i can't define the variable... but how to remove those?

Comment: @Arkonsol - unfamiliar with php myself but in some cases the server side has the ability to specify a header to indicate the data type. Usually this defaults to HTML but when using JSON there is maybe another setting to give. Judging by the error message there is a < at the start of the string but you did not post that so my money is on the server chucking in some markup. Have a look here there are some examples down the page.

Comment: my problem exactly. them brackets are not even supposed to exist! D: i even tried to stringafy the hell out of that thing but it's still there....

Comment: `[]` are used to denote an array, in json. they are perfectly valid. The character which chokes the `JSON.parse()` is the `<`. This probably means your ajax request throws an error, which is presented as html (hence the `<`). Use the inspector to inspect the request itself, not call the sing.php file directly, and read what the page returns.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the html from sing.php and only return JSON. Even though you see the correct output in your browser, if you view the source you'll notice the , etc. tags. Your script is seeing those and failing.

Comment: i experimented with that but then it just says undefined... :/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the AJAX request returns HTML, you can check what's being returned by using an alert, change the code to this:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
```

If there is HTML in the alert, you should check if the path of the sing.php page is correct in the line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "sing.php", true);
```

Comment: it has the correct one now that i deleted the html and body tags but then it still remains undefined...

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED ANSWER.**

Ok, I checked everything and had a local setup. You have many mistakes in your code.

Let's take a look at index.html.

It should look like this. (I added comments where you made mistakes.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Get data as JSON from a PHP file on the server.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj, i, x, j = "";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(this);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        myObj = JSON.parse(this.response); //**IT'S 'response' NOT 'responseText' To look at the object data, you can do console.log(myObj) and see what the object looks like. in the developer window**

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.student_id; //**YOU DON'T HAVE A PROPERTY 'id' BUT YOU DO HAVE 'student_id', again look at the json object in the developer window. **
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "sing.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As for 'sing.php', since I don't have your database, I created my own arrays so that I could merge them since I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
<?php

$outp =  array(
  'student_id' => '10-00000',
  'student_name' => 'Breaker M. North',
  'student_course' => 'BSIT',
  'student_stat' => 0,
  'student_log' => 1
);

$outp2 =  array(
  "stu_log" => 2,
  "course_name" => "IT 202",
  "student_id" => "10-00000"
);

echo json_encode(array_merge($outp, $outp2));

?>
```

When you do `echo json_encode($outp + $outp2);` you're actually creating and new array and putting `$outp` and `$outp2` as separate values. That's why you had the [], you had two values and not only one. You then had `undefined` because you couldn't access the property, instead you we accessing the first element of the json array.

On a side note, you could create only one SQL request by using `JOIN on student_id`... but this is not part of the question.

Comment: @Arkonsol just updated the whole answer. Found 3 major errors and explained why it didn't work.

Comment: yeah but ever since i want it as an object i'm guessing the brackets are not welcomed that's why it's undefined but i keep trying to errase those but their still there

Comment: @Arkonsol The brackets only mean that you have an array of objects. You will always have brackets when you use json_encode in PHP. You errors are elsewhere as I mentioned in the code.